# What means "Harmonic function is radially symmetric?"

Tags: analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian, poissons-equation

I was wonder about following statement. "Harmonic function is radially symmetric."
What is correct meaning about above statement? I think it means 'Harmonic function is invariant under rotation'

i.e: Let u(x) is harmonic function and x is n-dimensional vector. If A is nxn orthogonal matrix, then u(Ax) is also harmonic function

Is it correct?

Comment: Almost correct. A rotation is an orthogonal matrix with determinant one. To be clear: not every harmonic function is radially symmetric.